# mod_rewrite and PATH_INFO with php project

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a project that reads the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable when loading pages, therefore it reads pages in the format of http://address/index.php/pagename and I would like to use mod_rewrite to remove the index.php part of the url and make the previous URL http://address/pagename. If one visits http://address/pagename, it needs to load the page as if that person visited http://address/index.php/pagename.

With Nginx, the following configuration works and does the rewrite...

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /srv/http/web/html;
    index  index.php;

    location ~ ^/[^/]+\.php($|/) {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/[^/]+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ .* {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }
}
```

How would I accomplish this in apache. I currently have it working so that the root displays correctly and writing urls with the index.php part works. How can I make the rewrite rule work and still be able to use the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable? What could I put in the .htaccess to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly change `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` variable from within apache when php is compiled like a module.

But here's a workaround that will do the job just fine:

1. Create a `rewrite_pathinfo.php` file with the following contents:

   ```
   <?php
   if (!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
   $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_ORIGINAL_PATH'];
   ?>
   ```
2. Put this into your `.htaccess`:

   ```
   php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/vhosts/path_to_your/rewrite_pathinfo.php"

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [QSA,L,PT,E=ORIGINAL_PATH:/$1]
   ```

Comment: Just because I want to understand what's going on, can you explain what's going on in step 2? I've also never used `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_ORIGINAL_PATH']`. Where or how is this index set?

Comment: Can you confirm if the solution works for you? I'll add some comments right away...

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: I changed the prepended PHP code to one that actually redirects from /index.php/example to /example (previous version just retained the PATH_INFO variable). Also please correct your .htaccess if it had `RewriteEngine On` on the first line due to buggy list formating on this website. It works on my Apache 2.4.18, what version do you have?

Comment: Nope, does not work on the setup I'm trying. I'm getting an "Object not found!" page. My Apache version is 2.4.18 from Arch Linux's [extra].

Comment: Got nothing else?

Comment: I made a silly typo and it fixed my problem, thanks for your help!